# Layout not rendering properly as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my index action I have

```
@posts = Post.all
```

This is my `index.html.erb`.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="columns large-12 small-12 medium-12">
</div>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Posts</h1>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Body</th>
  <th>Body</th>
  <th>Body</th>
  <th>Body</th>
</tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
  <%= @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td>  <%= post.id %>        </td>
    <td>  <%= post.title %>     </td>
    <td>  <%= post.body %>      </td>
    <td > <%= link_to 'Show' %> </td>
    <td > <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %> </td>
    <td>  <%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete %> </td>

  </tr>

  <% end %>
  </tbody>

</table>
<%= link_to 'NEW POST', new_post_path  %>


</div>
```

It is rendering fine except that the `@posts` object is printing in a form like below just above the `table` tag in my browser. I know it is something silly but I can't figure that out.

`[#<Post id: 4, title: "new title", body: "this is new body", created_at: "2015-12-21 07:44:42", updated_at: "2015-12-21 10:31:31">, #<Post id: 7, title: "new title", body: "dfdsfd", created_at: "2015-12-21 09:40:01", updated_at: "2015-12-21 09:40:01">]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hai just remove the '=' in the @posts.each line.
<%@posts.each do |post| %>, thats it.

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="columns large-12 small-12 medium-12">
</div>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Posts</h1>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Body</th>
  <th>Body</th>
  <th>Body</th>
  <th>Body</th>
</tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td>  <%= post.id %>        </td>
    <td>  <%= post.title %>     </td>
    <td>  <%= post.body %>      </td>
    <td > <%= link_to 'Show' %> </td>
    <td > <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %> </td>
    <td>  <%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete %> </td>

  </tr>

  <% end %>
  </tbody>

</table>
<%= link_to 'NEW POST', new_post_path  %>


</div>
```

Comment: It happens sometimes when we are new to rails.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was something really really silly! The `erb` template engine requires `=` with `erb` tags to display the data while the logic is written without using the `=`.

It was just a simple change like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %> # without the = symbol
```